# ASP.NET - Gridview Data Filtering on Client-Side based on Keypress on textbox

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, asp.net

I want to do a process of CLIENT-SIDE data searching on gridview for faster loading and performance (data on GV is being loaded by a stored procedure)

I have seen this as source and tried to follow the codes but it is not working. What could be wrong? [Filter records in gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494817/filter-records-in-gridview)
http://www.vonloesch.de/comment/reply/23

Here's what I have got

```
function filter2(phrase, _id) {
    var words = phrase.value.toLowerCase().split(" ");
    var table = document.getElementById(_id);
    var ele;
    for (var r = 1; r < table.rows.length; r++) {
        ele = table.rows[r].innerHTML.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, "");
        var displayStyle = 'none';
        for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            if (ele.toLowerCase().indexOf(words[i]) >= 0)
                displayStyle = '';
            else {
                displayStyle = 'none';
                break;
            }
        }
        table.rows[r].style.display = displayStyle;
    }
}
```

---

```
     <!-- A text box for entering search phrase and GridView1.ClientID returns the client id of gridview -->
 <input name="txtTerm" onkeyup="filter2(this, '<%=grdLocation %>')" type="text">
```

---

```
             <div class="ModalBodyGridview">

      <asp:GridView ID="grdLocation"  runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" Width="420px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="grdLocation_SelectedIndexChanged" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" EmptyDataText="No records Found" >
   <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
  <Columns>
      <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="Location Num" HeaderText="Location Num" SortExpression="Location Num" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="Location Name" HeaderText="Location Name" SortExpression="Location Name" />
   </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
         <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="green" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FBFBF2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#848384" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#EAEAD3" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#575357" />
      </asp:GridView>


     <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RPSMSConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="spSearchLoc" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
```

OR IF ANYBODY CAN SUGGEST ANOTHER SOLUTION, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass the `ClientID` to the JavaScript function you have. Because your `GridView`'s ID will be different in client side once it's rendered.

Try this

```
<input name="txtTerm" onkeyup="filter2(this, '<%=grdLocation.ClientID %>')" type="text">
```

Comment: i see... i'm sorry , how to vote up? all along i thought that is how you vote for an answer

Comment: Thank you. That helps to increase my reputation in SO ;)

Comment: I have additional question, how can I autofocus the cursor on the html textbox?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to give focus to a text input using JavaScript do the following

**In JavaScript**

Let's say your markup looks like this

```
<input id="txtTerm" name="txtTerm" onkeyup="filter2(this, '<%=grdLocation.ClientID %>')" type="text">
```

In JavaScript do the following to give the focus to that element

```
document.getElementById("txtTerm").focus();
```

**In code behind**

You may have to use `runat="server"` in your markup as follows.

```
<input id="txtTerm" name="txtTerm" onkeyup="filter2(this, '<%=grdLocation.ClientID %>')" type="text" runat="server">
```

Then, just call the [Focus()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus(v=vs.110).aspx) function

```
txtTerm.Focus();
```

**UPDATE 1**

Don't use `runat="server"` if you are going with a `JavaScript` approach.

```
<input id="txtTerm" name="txtTerm" onkeyup="filter2(this, '<%=grdLocation.ClientID %>')" type="text">
```

If you are using a ModalPopupExtender use the following JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        Sys.Application.add_load(modalSetup);

        function modalSetup() {
            // Use the correct ModalPopupExtender id here
            var modalPopup = document.getElementById(<%= ModalPopupExtender1.BehaviorID %>);
            modalPopup.add_shown(SetFocusOnControl);
        }

        function SetFocusOnControl() {
            var textBox1 = document.getElementsByName("txtTerm")[0];
            textBox1.focus();
        }
</script>
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: I followed your code, yes it is already focusing on the textbox but the keypress event stopped working after putting the runat="server". Please be noted that they are on modalpopupextender thanks

Comment: I tried putting autofocus="autofocus" as attribute in the input textbox, it did worked focusing the cursor to the textbox without affecting the keypress event, but for the second time of modalpopupextender showing, it is no longer focused.

Comment: so , that's a another javascript code apart from the keypress one?

Comment: yes it is. But, you can try to merge. that's up to you.

Comment: it actually worked but not fully, because i forgot to tell that I have a server-side process in it, I have a dropdownlist that whenever the user choose one item there, the modal will pop-up automatically, after putting the javascript code, the process no longer worked but it did focused the cursor to the textbox.

Comment: So you are keeping your secrets to your self. I can't read your mind. So I answered to your question.

Comment: I'd suggest you to create a new question rather than continuing here. I'll answer there. Give full details. What's working and what's not etc with sample code.

Comment: Done. please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27540546/asp-net-focus-cursor-on-textbox-inside-a-modalpopupextender-based-on-condition